# Saving all simple calculations or performing them each time results are required?

Tags: c++, performance

So I am doing long simulations, basically in C++. I have several classes with lots of members and several operations that needs to be done and redone. There are lot of simple task that needs to be done several time.
For big calculations, I have calculated them once and saved it as member. But for simple calculations like addition and subtraction of other members, calculating norm of member array etc., I am confused if saving them also wise decision to boost performance.
For these kind of simple task, is it faster to just calculate each time needed or save the results of calculations as new members and retrieve when needed.

I have many of these simple repetitive calculations so this can make the code really tedious, putting getters, setters  for all.

Comment: Like most of everything else, it depends. How often will you do these "small" calculations? How often will the values involved change? Have you tried to measure both attempts?

Comment: Only one way to know: measure. Whether caching something will be a net win or not cannot be answered in general.

Comment: If your goal is improvement of performance, you need to make many tests to find bottle necks and check which approach is better in your case.

Comment: values change with each time step. but for each time step ~100 operations are doing same simple calculation (add, subtract, norm). about measuring this would be pretty down the line as right now i am just writing the code and need to put in several things before i could run. I can do very simple test, like time difference in just retrieving the value from member and calculating norm. but that would not give a good clear picture.  so i wanted to ask if there were know difference better calculations and retrieve values.

Comment: "Too broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." i.e. we have no idea what you are doing, and by the sounds of it, you've not even done it yet... so how can anyone say?

Comment: perhaps the question was too board. I just wanted to see if there were any opinions on whether saving all calculations or calculating it was better.

Comment: The opinion is, clearly: "it depends." And it does. With getters and setters you're trading calculation for a subroutine call. But there are other alternatives. What if the object had a `.recalculate` method that updated a slew of individual property-variables, all at once? When using setters, also consider which calculations are truly "hot spots," both time-consuming and frequently called-for.

Comment: @hadik One solution you can consider is to use a recursive algorithm with your statistics. This way, you can have an online sum, average, etc. This is similar to how C++ tracks the size of a vector -- incrementing it and decrementing a value as objects are inserted or removed from the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Memoization isnt that tedious. You can get it easily like this:

```
template <class OUT,class IN>
OUT calc(const IN& x){

    // (small) overhead for memoization
    static std::map<IN,OUT> memo;
    std::map<IN,OUT>::iterator found = memo.find(x);
    if (found != memo.end()){ return found->second; }

    // (possibly expensive) calculation 
    double result = doTheCalculation(x);   // the actual calculation
    memo[x] = result;
    return result;

}
```

When you do this in a clever way, you dont even have to write the memo code for each function where you want to use it but simply reuse it for several functions. Whether it is worth to do this completely depends on your application and the only way to find out is to measure it.

Note that the above might be more efficient by reaplacing the `map` with an `unordered_map`.